# What is a pressurized filter, and should I use it for my espresso?

Tags: coffee, espresso

I've just started out really using my Gaggia Classic espresso machine, and so far I've been pretty satisfied with my results – but I'm no expert. Yesterday, I lost the black plastic thing that goes between the portafilter and the basket (is that the right terminology?), as shown below:

[image]

Now, when I tried to make espresso without it, I noticed that the liquid would spray from the portafilter and, well, ruin my kitchen. When I researched further, it seemed that I didn't even use a normal filter, but something called a "pressurized filter", where there's only one hole in the bottom for the coffee to come out.

Here's what I found out about it [on coffeegeek.com](http://coffeegeek.com/opinions/markprince/07-20-2004#101):

> […] a crema enhancing device is built into the actual filter basket, usually through the function of channeling all the brewed coffee through a solitary pin hole. This action creates a jet-like effect that boosts crema production, even in stale coffee or coarse ground coffee.

People on the internet seem to hate this thing though, and I start wondering whether I should get a replacement for this bolt, or just buy a "normal" filter. Here are my questions:

- What exactly is the purpose of this "enhancement"? How does it work?
- Why should I use it, or why shouldn't I? Does it matter for me as a non-professional?

Comment: I'm also using a Classic, and it's a pretty neat machine. Make sure you replace your steam wand with a real one (no 'auto frother tube thing') and get a good grinder to match it, and you'll be able to make fine espresso. (if you aren't already, that is :) )

Comment: @Max Although I was getting good results, I'm looking into replacing it anyway — have you got any recommendations?

Comment: @slhck why do you want to replace it? I have had my Gaggia Classic for 18 months, and love it. The only real problem is the POOR steaming capability. I fixed that by installing a PID kit from Auber Instruments - at $200 it was much less $$$ than a new espresso machine.

Comment: @RickG I tried the steamers of "real" machines and found them a bit better to use than these plastic auto frothers. Do you mean [this kit](http://www.auberins.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=35)? How exactly does it help? I'm a poor noob when it comes to espresso, I have to admit.

Comment: @slhck uhhh my bad - I thought you were replacing the entire machine. I actually bought [the PID-GGS kit from Auber](http://www.auberins.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=6&products_id=228), which includes the ability to control the steam boiler. It replaces the thermostats for both the steam and the brew temperature, which gives you much more consistent temperatures for both. The result of installing the PID kit is two-fold: better espresso, and better steaming capability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called a pressurized portafilter. As you found on coffeegeek, it is designed to enhance production of crema. The Coffee Geeks look down on this device, since it produces what is essentially "fake" crema - even with old, stale pre-ground coffee.

If all you want to drink are lattes, it does not make much difference. If you want to taste decent espresso, then you must use a non-pressurized portafilter - even if you are a non-professional.

Making espresso is not a slam dunk - especially with a consumer machine like the Gaggia. You will learn to improve your espresso shots by analyzing your technique. This often is based on the appearance of the crema during and after the shot is drawn.

Since the pressurized portafilter gives you misleading information on the actual crema, you will have difficulty learning how to make a good espresso.

Comment: By the way: Got my new "classic" filters today and I think I did pretty well. Maybe I'll try a bottomless portafilter next for learning.

Answer (score 0):

i have given this topic much thought and research too..

at the end of the day, it depends on how you like your coffee, how frequent and how much you make weekly too..

if you go through the trouble of getting fresh beans.. freshly roasted... with a great burr grinder.. then sure it would be best if you had a non pressurized portafilter...

also u gotta ensure ur machine has consistent temperature.. pressure and a bunch of other technical stuff...

let's not forget the right steps to preparing and pulling a great shot! preperation, descaling etc etc..

on top of all that.. you need to use the beans you buy within weeks.. as non pressurized pf really exposes the beans qualities.. so if it's not fresh.. it's probably going to taste bad..

you finally end up with great espresso shots (hopefully).. and you can enjoy it black.. americano..  or a tiny bit of milk..

if you are going to milk it up.. and make lattes etc.. add sugar and syrups... then my suggestion would be to stick to a simple pressurized setup where u don't have to worry too much about age of bean (to a certain extent)... you also don't have to get the grind size perfect or the tamping...

anyways just my two cents..

i like a pressurized for a home setup.. and at work where i run restaurants we have professional machines to play with..

cheers!  don't forget.. most importantly.. enjoy you coffee!